# materialize entire kafka topic into rocksdb

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I'm currently doing a POC of kafka streams wherein I'm trying to use kakfa as a messaging bus as well as a database.
I'm trying ksql for the second purpose. I'm able to query the topic using ksql but it takes a long time as ksql reads the entire topic every time and filters it at client side.
Is there any way to materialize the entire topic as a state store in kafka?

Comment: "as a state store in kafka" -- if you mean broker side: no.

Comment: What do you mean by "ksql reads the entire topic every time" -- this would only happen if you terminate a query...

Comment: My requirement is to use kafka as a mysql table where I want all historical data to be returned on a query..so i had to configure ksql to ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset=earliest

Answer (score 0):

You can read a topic as KTable and force a state store materialization to access the content via Interactive Queries API.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
 KTable<Integer, Integer> table = builder.table(
   "topicName",
   Materialized.as("queryable-store-name"));
```

Comment: Can we query historical data using interactive queries?